# socket send() replying with leading "%s "

Tags: sockets, ftp, send

I am trying to implement an ftp server with the following code:

```
 64         if (command_sock == -1){
 65                 printf("error accepting socket connection: errno = %d\n", errno);}
 66         else{printf("connection accepted\n");}
 67 
 68         send(command_sock, "220 FTP Server ready\n", 25, 0);
 69 
 70         int image_mode = 0; //not set to "I"
 71         int file_str = 1; //file mode by default
 72 
 73         while(1){
 74                 recv(command_sock, buffer, 512, 0);
 75                 sscanf(buffer, "%s %[^\n]s", command, arg);
 76                 printf("command = \"%s\"\n", command);
 77                 printf("arg = %s\n", arg);
 78 
 79
 80                 if(strcmp(command, "USER") == 0){
 81                         send(command_sock, "230 user logged in\n", 35, 0);
 82                 }
 83                 else if(strcmp(command, "QUIT") == 0){
 84 
 85                         close(command_sock);
 86                         close(send_1);
 87                         goto listen;
 88 
 89 
 90                 }
```

But when I try and login it is failing because the line 81 is really sending "%s 230 user logged in\n".

```
root@nodeforcetwo:/home/rustyventure/opsys/mac_5# ftp
ftp> open 127.0.0.1 3500
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220 FTP Server ready
Name (127.0.0.1:rustyventure): rusty
%s 230 user logged in
Login Failed
```

Can anyone see why, I am at a loss here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In line 68 you send 25 bytes, but the string you want to send contains only 21 bytes. You end up sending an additional 4 bytes of whatever is in memory after that string constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
"220 FTP Server ready\n"
```

is 21 bytes, not 25, but the line terminator in FTP is `\r\n`, not `\n`, so it should be:

```
send(sock, "220 FTP Server ready\r\n", 22, 0);
```

Also you are making the common mistake of ignoring the count returned by `recv()`. It can be:

- -1, meaning an error
- 0, meaning end of stream: the peer has disconnected
- > 0, meaning the number of bytes that were actually transferred.